# Inherited software that's built on Visual FoxPro, How can I access the source files and edit the program as needed?

Tags: visual-foxpro

There are certain features and bugs that we need to fix, and the company that sold us the software has gone out of business and halted support. Does anyone know how to do this sort of thing?

Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is why, when buying closed-source software, it is imperative to get the vendor to agree to set up [source code escrow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Source_code_escrow).

It is quite possible, such a thing was arranged in the vendor's case. Your legal department ought to check the agreement carefully.

If not, see if you can find any developers, who used to work there -- they may even have copies of sources somewhere...

There is no technical solution -- the binaries can not be decompiled...

Comment: Amazing, this genuinely became the best answer. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: @user1746302, it is not true that there is no technical solution. VFP binaries can be decompiled, provided you don't have a legal problem (when done to my code I see it as pirating).

Comment: @CetinBasoz, I'll be feathered, how would one decompile them? I've done it to Java JARs and classes, but never to FoxPro...

Comment: @MikhailT, I thought anyone using Foxbase, Foxpro, VFP knows refox, defox. Personally I am against them as they mean pirating to me.

Comment: I last used FoxPro 20+ years ago, but we were compiling executables... Yours would be a better answer to @OP then -- I encourage you to post it as such. It is not piracy -- the vendor is out of business having left the customer high and dry...